# How to pass the JSON object in java function using JSNI?

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I am learning GWT, I am trying following example in which I have tried to pass the JSON object in java function.

```
public class HomeController implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {
    createTestNativeFunction();
    Presenter presenter = new PersenterImpl();
    presenter.go(RootPanel.get());

}

public native void createTestNativeFunction()/*-{

        parser: function() {
            var that = this;
            var jsonResult = JSON.parse({id:42,name:'yo'});
            return this.@com.easylearntutorial.gwt.client.HomeController::onParse(Lorg/sgx/jsutil/client/JsObject;)(jsonResult);
        }

        void onParse(jsonResult){
          System.out.println(jsonResult);
        }
    }
}-*/;
}
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.easylearntutorial.gwt.client.HomeController'
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/ameen/workspace/Tutorial/src/com/easylearntutorial/gwt/client/HomeController.java'
[ERROR] Line 31: missing ; before statement
        void onParse(jsonResult){
--------------------------------^
[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[WARN] Server class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JDBCUnloader' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Program%20Files/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/C:/Program%20Files/gwt-2.7.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
```

Comment: Is it commented out like that in your code?

Comment: @Jim Garrison Thank you!!, Please help me to learn how you edited the errors section in the question

Comment: Click the "edited 1 hour ago" link to compare the two versions.

Comment: @JimGarrison okay!!. You have corrected the Indentation. This is what I think?

Comment: @Ameen see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should try to avoid JSNI. You can probably write 99% of your code not using JSNI at all. If you really need it, you should use the new JsInterop instead, documentation still in early stage but you can see this [documentation here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit?usp=sharing).

If you need to use JsInterop or JSNI it is usually because you need to wrap a JS lib, so first, try to find if it is already wrapped. If it is not you can always use some other wrapper library to learn how to wrap your JS lib.

- OpenLayers JsInterop wrapper https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-ol3
- OpenLayers JSNI wrapper (deprecated) https://github.com/geosdi/GWT-OpenLayers
- Or explore github https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Agwt+topic%3Ajsinterop

Comment: Also, use this chat to ask quick questions, ask for suggestion, or some initial guidance, etc. https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` is a java function, you are looking for `console.log()`.

The body of the `native` is JavaScript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are declare you variable jsonResult into your parser: function(), jsonResult only exist into that function. Thats why the system say you that 
missing ; before statement
Because you never declare the varieble into createTestNativeFunction().

Plus sjakubowski is right System.out.println() is a java function, you need to use console.log() on JavaScript.

Try this:

```
public native void createTestNativeFunction(){
    var jsonResult = {};

       parser: function() {
        var that = this;
        jsonResult = JSON.parse({id:42,name:'yo'});
        return this.@com.easylearntutorial.gwt.client.HomeController::onParse(Lorg/sgx/jsutil/client/JsObject;)(jsonResult);
    }

    void onParse(jsonResult){
      console.log(jsonResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve my errors.

```
public class HomeController implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {
    createTestNativeFunction();
    Presenter presenter = new PersenterImpl();
    presenter.go(RootPanel.get());

}
//  var jsonResult = JSON.parse({id:42,name:'yo'});
public native void createTestNativeFunction()/*-{
    var that = this;
    $wnd.testFunction = function(jsonResult) {

        that.@com.easylearntutorial.gwt.client.HomeController::onParse(Lorg/sgx/jsutil/client/JsObject;)(jsonResult);   
    };  

}-*/;

 public void onParse(JsObject jsonResult){
     int i =42;
 }
```

}